# How to check if a laptop's HDMI port is powered (for VGA adaptor)?

Tags: laptop, hdmi, power

The Lenovo Y50 (Win 8.1 Pro) only has an HDMI port and I will be giving a presentation where only a VGA port is available. I can get an HDMI to VGA adaptor that does not need to be powered (via micro-USB) if the HDMI port provides at least 200mA.

Does the HDMI port provide power? If so how much does it provide? Is there a way I can see this in the ports settings under Device Manager in Control Panel?

Comment: *Does the HDMI port provide power?* - this question makes me slightly uncomfortable. HDMI is a digital and VGA is analog. Any convertor in between would require power to operate. I do not know of any such self powered convertors yet. Look at this [product](http://www.conversionstechnology.com/v/Files/CTHDMI-VGA%20PS.pdf) which requires 5V DC to work. You should be able to power (5V, 2A) it from your phone charger with suitable adapters

Comment: @Prasanna Please read the question. It clearly recognises that the converter needs to be powered. Later versions of HDMI provide power. I am asking how to check if the one in my laptop is one that provides power.

Comment: <quote> *I am asking how to check if the one in my laptop is one that provides power.* <unquote> Of course your laptop is one that can power the line if the later versions of HDMI provide power. What do you finally want to find out? The power load on the HDMI port when the convertor is connected?

Comment: @Prasanna It is not an "of course" as I don't know which HDMI standard the port supports, and I don't know the standard that started supporting power, and I don't know the power throughput of the standard it supports (if any), and I don't know the physical power throughput the port supports (if any).

Comment: I don't have an answer, but the [hdmi site](http://www.hdmi.org/learningcenter/kb.aspx?c=13#42) says the spec guarantees a minimum of 55 milliamps on the 5volt pin, but "most source devices on the
market today provide significantly more current".

Comment: If you're so unsure of what the laptop is capable of, then the prudent course is to use a HDMI-to-VGA converter that requires external power. That's what I use (it looks the one in Prasanna's link) (and it also has HDCP).